# How to implement Anycast DNS

Tags: domain-name-system, domain, nameserver, dns-zone, anycast

Our website hosting provider uses Anycast DNS and has a zone file with a set of nameservers as shown the this screenshot for the zone **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)**

[image]

However the nameservers for the domain are different as shown the the screenshot.

[image]

On changing the nameservers of the domain to the same as the ones in the Anycast zone file the DNS caching (propagation) changes show for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) but not so much for example.com even after 45 hours.

DNS Propogation check for **[www.example.com](http://www.example.com)**

[image]

DNS Propogation check for **example.com**

[image]

Is this because more time is needed or is there something wrong in the way the nameservers are being setup?

Comment: While starting to write an answer it striked me that "for the zone www.example.com" is unclear. Do you mean `www` is really delegated at the DNS level? In short, your question will be far better if you give the real names involved, as anyone could then do tests. In the meantime you have the following online troubleshooting tools: dnsviz.net and zonemaster.net

Comment: It says SOA and below that Zone and against zone www.example.com

Answer (score 1):

Anycast services should be totally transparent to the user, unless the provider is doing it incorrectly. If your zone is not properly propagating, you may need to open a support ticket with the provider to get this moving again.

Over the years I have seen several organizations do DNS very differently. Some have a proper 'primary/master' where all others get DNS data from. A few use a stealth primary/master. Some break the chains and copy zone data and configuration elements to DNS servers one-by-one.

Propagation for zones and/or records should not take 45 hours. On the aspirationdns.com servers, changes should be reflected very quickly. The only time this can take longer is when records are cached by 3rd party DNS resolvers that wait until the record TTL expires to refresh. Some do...

Comment: "that wait until the record TTL expires to refresh. " All should do, that is the design of the DNS (and outside specific conditions like cache full, or explicit refresh, or other local optimizations). Which is why "propagation" does not exist in the DNS, and one does not have to wait any time before seeing the changes on the authoritative nameservers